# Compute yaw/pitch/roll in Hugin from known elevations and azimuths

Tags: panorama, hugin

I'm trying to create a pano with an accurately positioned horizon, i.e. I would like that the horizontal line in the middle of the output picture represents 0° elevation and the left/right borders are due east. I know the elevation and azimuth of some pixels in some of the photos. Is there a way to enter this data in Hugin, so that it automatically applies the correct yaw/pitch/roll?

The only other way I can think of is to generate the output with 0° yaw/pitch/roll and write a small Octave script that, given the known elevations, azimuths and output pixel coordinates, computes the needed rotations.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PanoTools Wiki page on [Perspective correction](https://wiki.panotools.org/Perspective_correction), tilt (pitch), pan (yaw), and rotation (roll) can be corrected, if you assign two (2) horizontal control point pairs and two (2) vertical control point pairs:

> Only few control point pairs are needed to correct for perspective distortion.
>
> **Camera tilted, panned and rotated** - set two pairs to two different vertical structures apart from each other and two pairs to different horizontal structures apart from each other. Optimize for Yaw, Pitch, Roll and eventually Field of View.